# Archlinux mysqld won't launch

Tags: mysql, archlinux

Cat' launch mysqld on my archlinux x64.

```
Job for mysqld.service failed. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

after `systemctl start mysqld`
in log

```
mysqld.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: timeout) since Mon 2015-04-06 22:07:24 UTC; 9ms ago
  Process: 18077 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 18077 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           `-control

Apr 06 22:07:24 atlas systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Apr 06 22:07:24 atlas systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Apr 06 22:07:24 atlas systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

What can i do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will get detailed info in systemd journal: `sudo journalctl -f` then, on an other terminal, start mysql: `sudo systemctl start mysqld` to get logs on the first terminal. You will likely get error messages that will help you figure out what goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You should type this command before starting the service

> `mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql`

ِAnd later you can start the service Regularly

For one session:

```
systemctl start mysqld
```

OR being enabled automatically on startup << (NOT RECOMMENDED)

```
systemctl enable mysqld
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the install instruction on the ArchLinux Wiki ?

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MySQL#Installation

As mentionned by Medo Tareq, you need to run the following command :

`mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql`

(Obviously you can adjust the parameters on the command, if you know what you are doing.)

The Wiki page also has other hint and information, notably about the `mysql_secure_installation` command that "will interactively guide you through a number of recomended security measures at the database level".

Answer (score -3):

Try change the permission of MySQL folder. If you are working locally and try to reinstall MySQL again after runing this command, it will work.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: Directory `/var/lib/mysql` belongs to packgage `mariadb`. Rights on files/directories that belong to a package are set by the packager on purpose. One should not modify these (if they are wrong after a fresh install then you should definitly open a bug report to the packager).