# mysqld.service failed because a timeout was exceeded

Tags: mysql

With this command:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysqld
```

I face with this error:

```
Job for mysqld.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: better suited for db.stackexchange.com. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522219/archlinux-mysqld-wont-launch http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216829/unable-to-launch-mysqld-in-arch-linux

Comment: you should edit your question and add the output of `systemctl status mysqld.service` and `journalctl -xe`.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have huge database that requires a lot of time to start.
If that's the case then you can change the service start timeout to something that will work for you. To do that add this line to the service file:

```
TimeoutSec=1200
```

or

```
TimeoutStartSec=1200
```

If you are using MariaDB then the file is located at this path:

```
/usr/share/mysql/systemd/mariadb.service
```

If you are using MySQL then probably the path is:

```
/usr/share/mysql/systemd/mysqld.service
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe related to selinux being set to enforcing. Have a look at /etc/selinux/config (on CentOS, location may vary on other distributions). If SELINUX=enforcing, try setting SELINUX=permissive and

- Reboot the machine
- Start MySQL if not already (sudo systemctl start mysqld)

In case SELINUX=enforcing is required, have a look at https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/practical-selinux-for-the-beginner-contexts-and-labels/ or other similar posts.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling `MySQL` might help:

1. Uninstall the current MySQL
2. Delete `/var/lib/mysql` and `/etc/mycnf` or `/etc/mycng.rpmsave`
3. `Reboot` the machine
4. Reinstall `MySQL`